# Проблема с большим текстом в сниппете

Tags: дефект, сниппеты

На примере вопроса [Как сделать чтобы загрузка файлов не отправлялась сразу на сервер?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/592134/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80#) можно заметить проблему с текстом в сниппете.

- EDGE 38.14393.0.0 Microsoft EdgeHTML 14.14393:

  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- Chrome Версия 54.0.2840.99 m:

  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- FF 50:

  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно связано с размером вставленного кода.

Comment: Для любителей чтения между строк.

Comment: Если переоткрыть окно сниппета, проблема не исчезает? Мне помогало :)

Comment: @Qwertiy, неа, там непонятно от чего зависит. Иногда еще и курсор как-то между строк скачет, но когда жмешь пробел например, переносит к нужному месту и вроде нормально начинает работать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как ответили на аналогичный вопросе на мете [Rendering glitch in Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322189/rendering-glitch-in-stack-snippet)

> This happens when a line of code is so long that it needs to be split in more than 50 editor lines - in your example, the line has about 2500 characters. This is a very extreme case so I'm doing a Steve Jobs here and telling you "Just avoid coding that way" :-)

Это все из-за длинных строк. Не используйте динные строки.

Comment: Лишь бы баги не фиксить.

Comment: @alexolut все-таки снипет должен быть человекочитаемым. Длинная строка на 2500+ символов - это неправильно.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, с другой стороны, 2500 не так уж и мало, для _минимального_ примера

Comment: @PavelMayorov для длинных строк должен работать автоперенос (как раз наш случай), и работать он должен корректно.